# Javascript - document.write() is working but document.innerHTML isn't

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a javascript countdown.  The countdown is working, just fine, but, when it reaches the countdown time, it starts counting backwards.  It should change the content of `#nextinternetbroadcast`.  It does change the content, if I use `document.write()`, but it overwrites the page (so I know the `if` is working).  For some reason, it simply is ignoring the `clearTimeout()` and `innerHTML` portion.

HTML (edited for terseness):

```
<div id="nextinternetbroadcast" class="link"></div>
<!-- page specific javascripts -->
<script>
// set a global javascript variable
var nextlivebroadcast;
// tell the function where the JSON data is
fetchJSONFile('http://www.flcbranson.org/api/livebroadcast', function(data){
    // do something with your data
    // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    // alert(data.datetime + ', ' + data.status);
    nextlivebroadcast = data.nextbroadcast;
});
// see if the global variable is still set (would say "undefined" if using an asychronous connection)
//alert(nextlivebroadcast);

// live broadcast countdown
cdtd(nextlivebroadcast);
</script>
```

JavaScript (edited for terseness):

```
// generic get JSON data function
function fetchJSONFile(path, callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
                if (callback) callback(data);
            }
        }
    };
    // false tells it to be synchronous instead of asynchronous
    httpRequest.open('GET', path, false);
    httpRequest.send(); 
}

// start javascript countdown (http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1248)
// don't forget to pass the broadcast variable
function cdtd(broadcast) {
    // just about any standard date format is accepted
    var nextinternetbroadcast = new Date(broadcast);
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = nextinternetbroadcast.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        document.getElementById('nextinternetbroadcast').innerHTML = '<a href="javscript:openVideo(' + livepublishingpoint + ');">Join live service now<\/a>';
        // document.innerHTML isn't working but document.write is (but it overwrites the whole page)
        //document.write('Something');
    }
    var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;
    document.getElementById('nextinternetbroadcast').className += " disabled";
    document.getElementById('nextinternetbroadcast').innerHTML = '<span class="days">' + days + '</span><span class="hours">' + hours + '</span><span class="minutes">' + minutes + '</span><span class="seconds">' + seconds + '</span>';
    // loop the function every second
    var timer = setTimeout(function() { cdtd(broadcast); }, 1000);
}
```

Am I doing something incorrectly?  I, certainly, am not seeing it.

**Edit (showing the fix in the JavaScript - thanks to Bergi)...**

```
// start javascript countdown (http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1248)
// don't forget to pass the broadcast variable
function cdtd(broadcast) {
    // just about any standard date format is accepted
    var nextinternetbroadcast = new Date(broadcast);
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = nextinternetbroadcast.getTime() - now.getTime();
    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
        document.getElementById('nextinternetbroadcast').innerHTML = '<a href="javscript:openVideo(' + livepublishingpoint + ');">Join live service now<\/a>';
        // document.innerHTML isn't working but document.write is (but it overwrites the whole page)
        //document.write('Something');
    } else {
        var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000);
        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);
        hours %= 24;
        minutes %= 60;
        seconds %= 60;
        document.getElementById('nextinternetbroadcast').className += " disabled";
        document.getElementById('nextinternetbroadcast').innerHTML = '<span class="days">' + days + '</span><span class="hours">' + hours + '</span><span class="minutes">' + minutes + '</span><span class="seconds">' + seconds + '</span>';
        // loop the function every second
        setTimeout(function() { cdtd(broadcast); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `document.body.innerHTML`?

Comment: I'm not too sure about JavaScript's scope in this case, but are you sure that the var timer is actually defined when you try to clear it?  var timer isn't declared as a timer until the very end of the function.  Every time the timeout calls the function again, you should be leaving the scope of your previous var timer.  Try declaring timer outside of the function?

Comment: crush Wouldn't that overwrite the page, too?  I'm just wanting to change the content of #nextinternetbroadcast.

Comment: @doubleJ I think people might be misunderstanding because you are referring to `document.innerHTML`, when you are actually using `document.getElementById(...).innerHTML`. (Aside: Regarding `document.write()`, it can only write into the current document if the current document hasn't been finished, i.e. if the script is run before the `</html>` ends).

Comment: @Bergi I start it with `cdtd(nextlivebroadcast);` in the HTML.

Comment: Why does your `fetchJSONFile` function have a callback if you're using it synchronously? Seriously, you should make it asynchronous.

Comment: @Lochemage I tried `var timer;` outside of the function, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Bergi I had to change it to synchronous, because I was needing to set global variables inside the functions.  Whenever I was doing it asynchronously, the variable would be set about half the time.  It probably doesn't need the callback portion, though.  I'm not a JavaScript wiz, but I can usually hack my way around pre-existing scripts and get them to do what I want.

Comment: @doubleJ: You shouldn't need that global variable. Instead start the countdown (and anything else that needs the `data`) from the callback: `fetchJSONFile('http://www.flcbranson.org/api/livebroadcast', function(data){
    cdtd(data.nextbroadcast);
});`

Comment: @Bergi I'm sure there are other ways to go about it.  In this case `fetchJSONFile()` is used multiple times for multiple things.  I was trying to be more modular, instead of just duplicating the same code over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing something incorrectly?

Yes, your `timer` logic is flawed. Currently you're doing

```
function fn() {
    if (/* no time left*/) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        // show end message
    }
    // show countdown
    var timer = setTimeout(fn, 1000);
}
```

You're trying to clear the timer before you've started it. And actually you don't have to do that at all, since at that time no timer is running. What you have to do instead is ensure that the timer is not restarted. So change the logic to

```
function fn() {
    if (/* no time left*/) {
        // show end message
    } else {
        // show countdown
        setTimeout(fn, 1000);
    }
}
```

Of course that doesn't really explain why your `innerHTML` assignment is not working (unless the flawed timer-cancelling led to some exception).

Comment: if I could give you +10 I would.